# SQL - How to Change values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to remove all 'abc/'
Can you please let me know how to write sql query?

Thank you.

```
id name
1 abc/1111.jpg
2 abc/2222.jpg
3 abc/3333.jpg
4 abc/4444.jpg
5 abc/5555.jpg
6 abc/6666.jpg
7 abc/7777.jpg
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, what have you tried?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. Sorry, I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can do this with standard syntax:

```
update t
     set name = replace(name, 'abc/', '')
     where name like 'abc/%';
```

Of course, there are better ways (this will replace all occurrences of `abc/` in `name`, not just the first), but the exact syntax depends on the database you are actually using.

In Postgres, you would more likely do:

```
update t
     set name = substr(name, 5)
     where name like 'abc/%';
```

This takes everything from the fifth character onwards.